# Linq's Column In (Select ...) Statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How do you write a linq statement that does the equivalent of this subselect in MS SQL:

```
... WHERE
tblXref.Organization_Id IN (SELECT Organization_Id
                   FROM AppUser au INNER JOIN [User] u ON au.User_Id = u.Id
                   WHERE u.Username = usernameVariable)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's probably simpler to write the inner query separately (remembering that you're not *executing* the query):

```
var innerQuery = from au in db.AppUsers
                 join u in db.Users on au.User_Id equals u.Id
                 where u.UserName == userNameVariable
                 select au.Organization_Id;

var query = from tblXref in db.CrossReferences // or whatever
            where innerQuery.Contains(tblXref.Organization_Id)
            ...;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to surround the innerQuery with .ToList() ?

Comment: @LePad: Absolutely not. Quite the opposite. If you call `ToList()`, that forces the inner query to be executed first, and all the results pulled back to the client - then sent *back* to the database for the second query. As I've written it, *everything* should get done in the database, in a single query.

Comment: It works! (And is a lot easier to understand as separate statements.) Thank you!

Comment: @JonSkeet: Could you please explaine why ToList forces the inner query to be executed alone?

Comment: @voo: Well I assume LePad meant calling `ToList()` at the end of the first statement. That means it has to fetch all the data to populate a `List<T>`. If the `ToList()` is only present in the second statement (`where innerQuery.ToList().Contains...`), then I'm not sure what the effect would be - it would be up to the query translator - but I can't see it providing any *benefit*.

Comment: @JonSkeet: if `ToList()` is inserted between `innerQuery` and `Contains`, then you will fetch all inner query results prior to the contains evaluation, right? I believe that is why there is a `Contains<T>()` ...??? :)

Comment: @IAbstract: No, it would still be part of the `Expression<T>` which is passed to the query translator. It *could* decide to pull all the results locally, but I'd hope it wouldn't.